# ListRasters not recognizing raster files in python

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.1, list, error-000732

I have 2 rasters in my workspace, one in TIFF Format and the other in GRID format: "C:\ExampleFolder"

When I use the python script:

```
import arcpy
>>> rasl=arcpy.ListRasters("C:\ExampleFolder")
>>> print rasl
None
```

Python does not recognize my raster files. I'm attempting to use the script in this previous question:

[Clip raster using shapefile into multiple rasters using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84969/clip-a-raster-using-a-shapefile-into-multiple-rasters)

I keep receiving error:
ERROR 000732: Input Rasters: Dataset does not exist or is not supported.

Any reason why Python does not recognize my raster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try explicitly defining the workspace:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\path\to\your\ws'
rasl = arcpy.ListRasters()
```

The [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000003w000000) shows that you cannot include the path of your workspace in the `ListRaster` function:

> The workspace environment must be set first before using several of
>   the List functions, including ListDatasets, ListFeatureClasses,
>   ListFiles, ListRasters, ListTables, and ListWorkspaces.

```
arcpy.ListRasters ({wild_card}, {raster_type})
```